# Can I join multiple nodes to a SQL Server failover cluster simultaneously?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I'm in the process of setting up a three-node SQL Server FCI. I have already created a WSFC and set up a SQL Server failover cluster on node1. Now, I need to add node2 and node3 to the failover cluster. My question is, can I add both nodes to the cluster simultaneously or do I need to add them one at a time?

Any insights or advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, can I add both nodes to the cluster simultaneously or do I need to add them one at a time?

Generally, you'll want to add them one after the other; however, setup won't puke or crash if you do them 'at the same time', especially with just two nodes. Going in sequential order does allow for fixing any mistakes or dealing with other issues that occur and is preferable but not required.

Most of adding a node to an FCI is checking the (remote) registry and installing the local services and binaries.